# Is there any documentation for building Xcode 4 plugins?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa, xcode4

Recently I've noticed a couple of projects on [github](http://github.com) that extend the functionality of Xcode 4 via plugins.

Two projects as examples by [@olemoritz](http://twitter.com/olemoritz):

- [MiniXcode](https://github.com/omz/MiniXcode) changes the main toolbar.
- [ColorSense](https://github.com/omz/ColorSense-for-Xcode) provides overlays to help pick colours.

Both projects are installed into `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins` and Xcode just picks them up.

Are there any sources of documentation (officlal or user generated) on extending Xcode?

**Edit:** [ping @olemortiz](https://twitter.com/sirjec/status/248045497963655168) ;)

Comment: AFAIK there aren't any. I guess @olemoritz just dumped stuff from the XCode executable itself and figured out part (if not all) of IDEKit. But the real question is ... why did you tag this question `ios`?

Comment: May we edit this question title to make it a generalisation of Xcode Plug (we're at Xcode 7 now..) ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As I wrote those plugins you mentioned, here are some pointers:

- There is no official documentation from Apple, so while Xcode does have a plugin infrastructure, it is entirely private API. (but hey, no one wants to submit Xcode plugins to the App Store, right? ;)) – The usual warnings apply: You should code very defensively, and it's possible that Xcode updates break things. Any plugin can bring Xcode down entirely, so be careful.
- There is a seemingly abandoned effort to document the plugin interface [here](https://github.com/phausler/XcodeAPI/wiki).
- There are some open source projects that allow you to see what's needed to get a plugin loaded at all, e.g. mine and there's [CLITool-Infoplist](https://github.com/0xced/CLITool-InfoPlist) (I think that's where I got the basic structure from, but I can't really remember, because I've been doing this without publishing anything for quite a while).
- You can use [class-dump](https://github.com/nygard/class-dump) to generate headers from Xcode's private frameworks, e.g. IDEKit and IDEFoundation (in `Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks`). Reading those gives you quite a bit of information on how Xcode is structured internally. DVTKit and DVTFoundation (in `Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks`) can also be useful to class-dump.
- You can observe all notifications that are sent in Xcode by registering an observer for `nil`. I initially just logged all those notifications to get an idea of where I might be able to hook into.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the great answer Ole, exactly the kind of detail I was looking for.

Comment: Some links are changed from above.
There is a seemingly abandoned effort to document the plugin interface [here](https://github.com/lroathe/XcodeAPI)

Answer (score 0):

There is no formal API or documentation.

Having said that nearly all community plugins are open sourced, use http://alcatraz.io to discover new plugins, then follow their github source code to learn how people are implementing them.

Here are some useful resources:

- Use https://github.com/edwardaux/XcodeExplorer to discover the API hook point you need to be poking around.
- Look at http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/creating-an-xcode4-plugin/ for a series of posts about building Xcode plugins.
- Check https://github.com/kattrali/Xcode-Plugin-Template for a Xcode 6+ template for creating new plugins.
- Look at https://github.com/zats/AdjustFontSize-Xcode-Plugin as a good Xcode 7.1+ starting point
- See http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/debugging-your-xcode-plugin/ for debugging aid