# How to find Xcode developer API

Tags: xcode

I want to write a plugin for Xcode,
however for that I need some api I can connect to, to change the behaviour of Xcode.

where can I find the API?

simply searching for "Xcode developer API" ,"Xcode developer class reference" , "Xcode API", only yields questions about it, not the official API?

Comment: There is no official API. Try forking any open-source Xcode plugin to see how it works.

Comment: so i have to "guess" which method to invoke ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a very related question answered a couple years ago, [there is no official documentation from Apple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12478484/981049).

But you're not entirely alone.

[Here's an Xcode 5 plugin template on GitHub](https://github.com/kattrali/Xcode5-Plugin-Template), and [some pointers in an article that talks about Plugin development for theXcode 4](http://danielbeard.io/blog/2013/04/30/developing-xcode-4-plugins/).

Comment: thank you, that's the most info i've received about it, since i started looking